# How can I test a button which uses props.history for it's onClick with react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

Here is the button in the component which uses props.history when user clicks on it .

```
<button data-testid="btn" onClick={ () => props.history.push(`/post/${value}`) } >Search</button>
```

And I tried testing the onClick it like this :

```
test('Button should navigate the url when enabled', () => {
        render(<Home />);
        const btn = screen.getByTestId('btn');
        fireEvent.click(btn);
    });
```

But it throws an error which is :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    > 21 |                                      onClick={() => props.history.push(`/post/${value}`)}
```

How can I make this work and solve this error so I can test the button which uses a prop for it's onClick function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this error by this code :

```
const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
render(<Home history={historyMock} />);
```